# User can only choose the value of enum (inside a textbox) in ASP.Net Core 6.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm wondering how to do this: the user has to choose a value inside of a textbox.

So the textbox is a drop down menu.

Here the user needs to select a **Category**

The items of textbox can be as following:

- Trendy
- Chic
- Oldschool
- Casual

I have these values listed in an enum.

Here is the enum:

```
public class OutfitVM
{
    public enum OutfitCategory
    {
        Trendy,
        Chic,
        Oldschool,
        Casual
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    private static int PlusÉénID = 1;
    [Required]
    public int Prijs { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public OutfitCategory Category { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Afbeelding { get; set; }
    public bool Retry { get; set; }
}
```

What I have tried to do is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult OutfitAanmaken(OutfitVM outfit)
{
    ViewBag.Category = outfit.Category;
    string FileNaam = UploadFile(outfit);

    outfitContainer.VoegOutfitToeZonderGebr(new utfit(outfit.Titel, outfit.Prijs, (Outfit.OutfitCategory)outfit.Category, FileNaam));

    return RedirectToAction("OutfitToevoegen");
}
```

The view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Category" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Category" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Category"></select>
</div>
```

If anyone knows a solution, let me know! I appreciate it.

Regards ^.^

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `asp-item` of the `select` tag to `Html.GetEnumSelectList<OutfitVM.OutfitCategory>()` to get the enumeration value.

Below is my test code,it works fine.

```
@model EnumTest.Models.OutfitVM
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Category" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Category" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<OutfitVM.OutfitCategory>()"></select>
</div>
```

Test Result:
[image]